# data modeling in JSON measure and it's dimensions

Tags: json

I have to program a web service returning JSON data. The data are measures (like employment rate) calculated across several combinaisons of dimensions.
I don't know how to model this in JON.
Here is my first naive model on an example

```
{
  TEMP: "employement rate"
  "value" : 20
  "unit" : "percent"
  "dimension" : { 
       "variable" : "FORMATION"
        "modality" : "CAP"
   }
  "dimension" : { 
       "variable" : "NSF3"
        "modality" : "PRODUCTION"
   }
}
```

The meaning is : the employement rate for student in CAP formation and in PRODUCTION speciality is 20% (so I have two dimensions, two group by in this example).
**The problem : how can I avoid the duplicate "dimension" key?**
Am I supposed to write "dimension_1" , "dimension_2", etc? 
I don't come across that problem with an XML output.

Yours sincerely
Loïc

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays?
If you only have 1 dimension, using an array with one element is fine.

```
{
  "TEMP": "employement rate"
  "value" : 20
  "unit" : "percent"
  "dimension" : [{ 
       "variable" : "FORMATION"
        "modality" : "CAP"
   },
   { 
       "variable" : "NSF3"
        "modality" : "PRODUCTION"
   }]
}
```